# C# Parse items from namespace

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML:

https://pastebin.com/YQBhNzm5

I want to match up the item values with the field values.

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(ofd.FileName);

XmlNamespaceManager xmanager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
xmanager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.canto.com/ns/Export/1.0");

var result = xdoc.SelectNodes("//ns:Layout/ns:Fields", xmanager);
foreach(XmlElement item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);

}
```

When I do this I get all the field names in one line. How can I iterate through all fields in layout and go one by one?

Comment: Please add a fragment of your XML to the question.  The issue is that eventually that pastebin will disappear, leaving your question orphaned.  Adding it directly to the question ensures your questions lasting value.

Comment: I'm not so experienced with this, but shouldn't you be searching for `//ns:Layout/ns:Fields/:ns:Field` if you want single fields. I guess your version just finds the `<ns:Fields>` tag, not the nested `<ns:Field>` tags.

Comment: I would add sample of XML but it is extremely large to paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I parsed xml using xml linq.  First I put items into a dictionary.  Then I parsed the fields looking up the uid from the dictionary.  I parsed the fields recursively to keep the hierarchy.

It looks like the uid, type, value, and name are always the same for each item, but an item can appear in multiple catalogs with a catalog id and an id.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Layout layout = new Layout(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Layout
    {
        public string tablename { get; set; }
        public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
        public Layout layout { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Item> dict = new Dictionary<string, Item>();

        public Layout() { }
        public Layout(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

            XElement xLayout = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Layout").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = xLayout.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ns");

            foreach (XElement item in doc.Descendants(ns + "Item"))
            {
                int catalogid = (int)item.Attribute("catalogid");
                int id = (int)item.Attribute("id");

                foreach(XElement fieldValue in item.Elements(ns + "FieldValue"))
                {
                    string uid = (string)fieldValue.Attribute("uid");
                    uid = uid.Replace("{", "");
                    uid = uid.Replace("}", "");
                    string innertext = (string)fieldValue;
                    string displayValue = (string)fieldValue.Attribute("displayValue");
                    List<string> categoryValues = fieldValue.Elements(ns + "CategoryValue").Select(x => (string)x).ToList();
                    if (!dict.ContainsKey(uid))
                    {
                        Item newItem = new Item() { 
                            catalogidId = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>() {new KeyValuePair<int, int>(catalogid, id)}, 
                            innertext = innertext, 
                            uid = uid,
                            displayValue = displayValue,
                            categoryValues = categoryValues
                        };
                        dict.Add(uid, newItem);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       dict[uid].catalogidId.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(catalogid, id));
                    }
                }
            }

            layout = new Layout();


            RecursiveParse(ns, xLayout, layout);


        }
        public void RecursiveParse(XNamespace ns, XElement parent, Layout layout)
        {
            layout.tablename = (string)parent.Attribute("tableName");
            foreach(XElement xField in parent.Element(ns + "Fields").Elements(ns + "Field"))
            {
                if (layout.fields == null) layout.fields = new List<Field>();

                Field newField = new Field();
                layout.fields.Add(newField);
                newField.uid = (string)xField.Attribute("uid");
                newField.uid = newField.uid.Replace("{", "");
                newField.uid = newField.uid.Replace("}", "");
                newField._type = (int)xField.Attribute("type");
                newField.value = (int)xField.Attribute("valueInterpretation");
                newField.name = (string)xField.Element(ns + "Name");
                if (dict.ContainsKey(newField.uid))
                {
                    newField.items = dict[newField.uid];
                }

                if (xField.Element(ns + "Layout") != null)
                {
                    Layout newLayout = new Layout();
                    newField.layout = newLayout;
                    RecursiveParse(ns, xField.Element(ns + "Layout"), newLayout);
                }

            }
        }


        public class Field
        {
            public string uid { get; set; }
            public int _type { get; set; }
            public int value { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public Layout layout { get; set; }
            public Item items { get; set; }
        }
        public class Item
        {
            public List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> catalogidId { get; set; }
            public string uid { get; set; }
            public string innertext { get; set; }
            public string displayValue { get; set; }
            public List<string> categoryValues { get; set; }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you